# How to surround all headlines with empty new lines in a markdown file?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression, global-command

I have the markdown file that uses `#` for headlines, like this one.

```
#H1
Text one one
##h2
more Text
#more H1s
Even more text
```

No I have the problem that some interpreters of markdown don't accept a headline when it isn't surrounded by empty lines.
So the upper file needs to look like this.

```
#H1

Text one one

##h2

more Text

#more H1s

Even more text
```

I thought I could write a function that gets executed when I write my changes to the file and I came up with this two functions

```
function! <SID>SurroundingNewLines()
    execute "normal! O\<esc>jo\<esc>"
endfunc

function! <SID>AddEmptyLines()
    1global/^#/execute "normal! o\<esc>"
    2,$global/^#/call <SID>SurroundingNewLines()
    %substitute/\n\{3,}/\r\r/e
endfunc
```

Please note that this is my first experience with VimScript.

The function `AddEmptyLines` searches for lines that start with a `#` and surrounds those with new lines and then the `substitute` command removes all duplicate empty lines.

This works but it is rather inefficient since it always adds the lines and then removes all unnecessarily added lines.

So is there a better way of doing this, for example find all headers that are not surrounded by empty lines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can have perhaps more cases than you account for in your description: a header line can be preceded by 0, 1 or many empty lines, and can be followed by 0, 1 or many empty lines. In all these cases, you want to achieve a header line preceded *and* followed by exactly 1 line (if I got that right). With this description, the problem can be solved with something like (I'm sure it can be improved):

```
:%s/\(^\s*\n\)*\(^#.*\)\(\n\s*\)*/\r\2\r\r/
```

or (similar, with more symmetry and slightly simpler):

```
:%s/\v^(\s*\n)*(#.*\n)(\s*\n)*/\r\2\r
```

Note that two headers following one right after the other will have 2 lines between them, but in a way this is a feature: in this way you can see that you still have to add some text there ...